# Devise authentication fails on first attempt, succeeds afterwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise (2.1.2) and Rails (3.2.9) and I've enabled basic authentication (for testing). I'm posting a JSON POST request using CURL and I'm seeing weird behavior. The authentication fails the first time I send the request (after server restart) but succeeds after sending the exact same request the second time.

When debugging, it seems that the winning_strategies are nil on the first attempt but populated with three strategies on the second attempt.

What is the cause of this behavior?

Comment: what's `winning_strategies` doing in user authentication?

Comment: I was just trying to debug it, `winning_strategies` is a list somewhere in Warden, I'm not familiar with Devise/Warden internals so it's just a hint for somebody more knowledgeable.

Comment: Is it only for JSON POST request using CURL? Do you able to login via browser?

Comment: Yes, browser login works properly.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: I don't remember doing anything against it but the fact is it doesn't happen anymore, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**Authenticate:**

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in \
  -d "{'user' : { 'email' : 'test@example.com', 'password' : 'password'}}" \
  -c cookie
```

**Show:**

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -X GET http://localhost:3000/pages/1.xml \
  -b cookie
```

For `post` requests -

You need a **CSRF token** for non-GET requests in Rails 3 .

This is because Rails by default adds an **authenticity token** to forms to protect from malicious forgery of submitted parameters. As you do not supply this token with your request, rails does not accept it. You can bypass this with

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

Comment: Yes, I see the message about CSRF token in the logs but it's only a warning and doesn't seem to have any effect. As I said, the exact same POST request fails the first time and works the second time (and every time after that). Why?

Comment: so that is the serious warning that may be getting out of first authentication for you. The second time, it gets the previous token somehow and you then gets authenticated. Seems again a `authenticity_token` issue. Try to bypass.

Comment: "The second time, it gets the previous token somehow..." - How? I get the warning the second time as well.

Comment: this is just a guess. I didn't saw your console after first and second but since using browser you are able to login, the only legal prob seems to be with `token` as json is external which can't be accepted directly by rails server. Try to bypass it.