# Devise Warden Authentication Fails First Time, Succeeds After

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, restful-authentication, warden

I am using Devise to authenticate users for my rails app using database authentication (for username and password) and token authentication for an API that I built with Grape. Devise is generating an authentication token as expected. However, it seems that authentication always fails after the first request and works subsequent times. I am calling `authenticate!` before my API calls in Grape, which is defined as follows:

```
def authenticate!
  error!({"error" => "Unauth 401"}, 401) unless env['warden'].authenticate
end
```

This is very odd behaviour. If I try to login with the browser first, then via a curl call to the API, it works. It seems that the first request will just always fail after a server restart.

Is that the expected behaviour? If so, why is that and how do I avoid it? Do authentication key logins always need a regular login via the browser first?

P.S: I did read [Devise authentication fails on first attempt, succeeds afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481771/devise-authentication-fails-on-first-attempt-succeeds-afterwards?rq=1), but it does not seem to answer the question.